# Unexpected element error in springboot soap webservice

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, soap

I am trying to create a soap webservice with springboot in  intellij with some tutorials. But getting the below error while submitting the request.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en">unexpected element (uri:"http://localhost:8080/students", local:"GetStudentDetailsRequest"). Expected elements are &lt;{}GetStudentDetailsRequest&gt;</faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

tutorial link [creating a soap webservice with springboot](http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-soap-web-service-with-spring-boot-web-services-starter)

student-details.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/students"
           xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8080/students" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="GetStudentDetailsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name= "id" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="GetStudentDetailsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name= "StudentDetails" type="tns:StudentDetails"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="StudentDetails">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="passportNumber" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Below is the objectfactory

ObjectFactory.java:

```
package com.example.epro.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;



@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    public ObjectFactory() {
    }


    public GetStudentDetailsResponse createGetStudentDetailsResponse() {
        return new GetStudentDetailsResponse();
    }

    public StudentDetails createStudentDetails() {
        return new StudentDetails();
    }

    public GetStudentDetailsRequest createGetStudentDetailsRequest() {
        return new GetStudentDetailsRequest();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show me your JAXB object factory and your XSD ?

Comment: Added both to the question.

Comment: Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758241/soap-envfault-in-wsdl